# Web browser stealing focus

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

i have two winforms loaded simultaneously 
first form with web browser and second form  having just controls 
second form always on top of second form, second form doesn't receive any mouse events while first form loaded, after closing first form, second form receive all mouse events.
how do i solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the code you're using to show for your second form, although it should be something like this:

```
Form2 myForm2 = new Form2();
Form2.Show(this);
```

It's not very likely that your WebBrowser is causing this.

Comment: fixed, thanks 
i have used
   Form2 myForm2 = new Form2();
   Form2.ShowDialog(this);
which causes the issue
Solved with following code
   Form2 myForm2 = new Form2();
   Form2.Show(this);